# facebook fanpage - nav menu in the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I've made a facebook fanpage, with some internal pages (http://on.fb.me/JP1HGi)

I'd like to add a navigation menu in these internal pages, so users can surf them like a "mini website" without exiting from the iframe, but after clicking on these menu buttons (expecially with internet explorer) it opens the page in another window; using other browsers, we can surf into the "mini website" but in the video page, if I click on a menu button, the new page opens in another window

Do you know if is it possible to make all pages viewable using this navigation menu, without exiting the iframe?

Thanks a lot

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one on the links in the menu:

```
<a href="YOUR_PAGE" target="_self">Videos</a>
```

Comment: thanks, now it works... but there is an issue on video page: in this page there is a content viewable only by fans, but now using this internal navigation this content isn't shown even if I'm a fan...

Comment: its because when you refresh the page, the access token is valid no more, save it in a session or a cookie and restore it from there....